# Why missing HttpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode Property in Blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I always get the response of HTTP like this as what Microsoft said(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.0) and it works well:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,string.Format(NavigationManager.Uri + "Callback/JSInitialise"));

        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = client.SendAsync(request);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string Content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
```

And now I used it in Blazor:

```
@inject IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory
@using SI_Customservice.Pages.Componets
@using System.Net.Http
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, string.Format(NavigationManager.Uri + "Callback/JSInitialise"));

        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = client.SendAsync(request);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string Content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
}
```

Meanwhile, Visual Studio reports this error:
[image]

Well, as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.issuccessstatuscode?view=netcore-3.0 said, it is in the Namespace of `System.Net.Http` which I have used it.

Why it still can not be recognized by Visual Studio yet?

Comment: You need to await the client.SendAsync call

Comment: @MarkPM well! It works immediately! What's wrong with this?

Comment: That returns a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` not `HttpResponseMessage`

Comment: @aguafrommars That's well, thank you.